# beacon array value is empty in didRangeBeacons in objective C

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

in my app i'm finding the beacons & want to calculate the Distance,here two days i struck with one problem that is in CCLocationManager delegate function returns empty beacons array.i tried the CBCentralManagerDelegate functions i get the list of beacons.in the didRangeBeacons method gives empty array help me. below is my code i tried

**Code:**

```
@interface ViewController ()<CBCentralManagerDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData *dat;
    CLBeaconRegion *clBeconRegion;

    CLLocationManager *locManager;
}
@property (strong,nonatomic) CBCentralManager *cbcManager;
- (IBAction)scanBtn:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.cbcManager=[[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    locManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locManager.delegate=self;
    [self initRegion];
    clBeconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;
    [locManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [self locationManager:locManager didStartMonitoringForRegion:clBeconRegion];
}
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"List of peripheral %@",peripheral);
    NSLog(@"List of advertisementData %@ %@",advertisementData,RSSI);

}

-(void)initRegion{
    NSUUID *uuid=[[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"];
    clBeconRegion=[[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"BluetoothExample"];
    clBeconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;
    clBeconRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
    clBeconRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
    [locManager startMonitoringForRegion:clBeconRegion];
}
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"didConnectPeripheral");
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

    [locManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:clBeconRegion];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"Entered Region");
     [locManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:clBeconRegion];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"Exit Region");
    [locManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:clBeconRegion];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"beacons %@ last %@",beacons,[region proximityUUID]);
    CLBeacon *beacon=[[CLBeacon alloc]init];
    beacon=[beacons lastObject];
     NSLog(@"min %@ maj %@",beacon.minor,beacon.major);
}
- (IBAction)scanBtn:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
    [self.cbcManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
    NSLog(@"scan clicked");
}
```

i'd fixed the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription info.plist.

i have a real beacon & ipad mini device.

this code is given in all beacon finding examples.help me what i did a mistake here.

Comment: If they are "real iBeacons", you shouldn't be able to see them with a `CBCentralManager`.

Comment: I would look over this if I were you: https://www.raywenderlich.com/101891/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-swift. Also consider naming your variables more verbosely. Cutting corners on naming and in general bad naming conventions (deviNamArr) are really frowned upon. deviNamArr = deviceNames or deviceNamesArray.

Comment: i'm getting this op using CBCentralManager: List of peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x17543310, identifier = 2B5678BE-6DD8-E8F7-EC8F-32ABE3EF5632, name = XY-1D54-64, state = disconnected>
2016-03-30 19:33:22.371 BluetoothExample[21355:3454631] List of advertisementData {
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = "XY-1D54-64";
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        "ABC24206-9BD7-034F-4FC9-ED1023171D54"
    );
} -70

Comment: ok  thank u i correct my variable naming @TheCodingArt

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- If you are not getting ranging callbacks, the ProximityUUID may be incorrect.  Use an off the shelf beacon detector like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) and verify you can detect the beacon and the ProximityUUID is what the CLBeaconRegion is set up to detect.
- Verify you have obtained location permissions properly by going to Settings -> (your app name), and verifying Location is set to "always"
- There is no need to use CoreBluetooth when detecting iBeacons.  You should remove all lines with classes that have the CB prefix.  While this code will give you a list of iBeacon Bluetooth devices nearby, it will not let you read the beacon identifiers.  You must use CoreLocation to do that.
- This method call is made by the CoreLocation framework, and should not be called manually.  It should be removed: 
  `[self locationManager:locManagerdidStartMonitoringForRegion:clBeconRegion];`

Comment: i already verified ProximityUUID as u said.Location in always only. CoreBluetooth is i have checked to get the UUID & name of beacon like that i used , then i tried only the CoreLocation & their delegate functions only it also giving empty array only.Finally i comment the calling the didStartMonitoringForRegion also.

Comment: Careful about the bluetooth device UUID you get from CoreLocation.  **This is NOT the same as the ProximityUUID used to detect beacons.**

Comment: help me @davidyoung http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576912/didenterregion-is-not-called-but-didexitregion-is-called-in-objective-c

Comment: I suspect the ProximityUUID used in code is not the one the beacon is transmitting.  I would check it again, this time not using CoreBluetooth, but instead using the Locate app here:  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8